# are after update triggers killed after a session kill (transaction rollback)?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

We had this really unwanted Update Query to our Table A. and this table contains a after-update-trigger that updates Table B,C. We killed the main transaction which was the Update statement on Table A, the question is did that also rolled back the changes on Table B and C? Or is the after-update-trigger even called at all? since we killed the session before the entire execution ended. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If...

- you are in a transaction, **and**
- all of the tables accessed are transactional tables (e.g. using InnoDB, not using e.g. MyISAM or MEMORY)

...then a rollback (including the implicit rollback from killing a session) rolls back *all* changes made within the transaction, including changes made by triggers, as well as cascading foreign key actions.

Triggers (and cascades) are never deferred in MySQL, so they would have fired `FOR EACH ROW` as the rows were being updated, but this is of course only academic since all changes they made would be undone with the rollback.

If table A is intact, then tables B and C should also be intact.  The safest course, of course, is to pull a recent backup and compare the current datafill to what you find in the backup, as a general sanity check.  This, of course, assumes frequent snapshot backups.